# ng new throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, npm, angular7

i'm usuing visual studio code for Angular applications and this is the first time that i find this kind of issue !

When i tried to create a new project and tap ng new projects-name i got this error :

```html
? Would you like to add Angular routing? (y/N) events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read EINVAL
    at TTY.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I don't even have versions issues ...well i guess :X

```html
Angular CLI: 7.1.2
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.11.2
@angular-devkit/core         7.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.1.2
@schematics/angular          7.1.2
@schematics/update           0.11.2
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.6
```

and npm version 6.5.0

Can anyone help me find out what's going on there ?
I tried to uninstall nodes and npm but still have the same issue

Thanks in advance and have a nice day :)

Comment: I'm also facing same issue while creating new project, @CarlaDX Is this issue resolved for you?

Comment: @Cegone Yes It did, I think the Problem was the Path. I tried to create a project in "C:" and got the same error Then i created a project in "D:\anotherFolder" and all was ok.

Comment: Hi, I've resolved this issue by this command
ng new foo-lib --routing --style=css

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution ^^ :) ! have a great day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved with this line command :

```
ng new foo-lib --routing --style=css
```